# Add empty row in excel using python pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I want to add an empty row to all of my excel files using python pandas.

I leave you an example so you can understand.

---

I have this:
[Excel example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMJuj.png)

[image]

---

And I want to add this row before name and city:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZDPX.png)

[image]

---

I need to do that, but not opening the excels files cause this is just a small example of what I really need.

Thanks!

Comment: You are going to have to open the file.. how else would you read/write to the file?

Comment: You know you can decide where the start row to input the data in excel right ?

Comment: @Wen yes, but i still need to add some extra empty rows at the top or middle, etc.

Comment: @Farhan.K read about pandas ;D.

Comment: Add empty row at particular index without replacing row values use : `df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.insert(df1.values, index+1, values=[" "] * len(df1.columns), axis=0),columns = df1.columns)`

Answer (score 4):

You can use startrow for this

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('demo.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Concentrado',startrow=1, startcol= 1, encoding='utf-8')
```

Answer (score 1):

Demo:

```
In [107]: df
Out[107]:
   a    b
0  a  zzz
1  b  yyy

In [108]: pd.DataFrame([[''] * len(df.columns)], columns=df.columns).append(df)
Out[108]:
   a    b
0
0  a  zzz
1  b  yyy
```

Comment: Thanks, i saw that answer on another post but i still got problems with that.

Comment: @Danitsu, what kind of problems?